# .htaccess matches files even without extension in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# If directory, redirect to root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]

# Don't show something.json
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule something\.json$ / [R,L]

# If not file or directory, go to the router
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /subfolder/router.php [L]

# Any other existing files get served normally
```

We can ignore the first two rules, they work. The problem is in the 3rd part/rule.

htaccess file is here:
 `https://subdomain.sitename.com/subfolder/.htaccess`

I need any non-directory and non-file addresses to go to `/subfolder/router.php`.

I have a html file on the server:
 `https://subdomain.sitename.com/subfolder/sub2/filename.html`

I want the URL:
`https://subdomain.sitename.com/subfolder/sub2/filename`
to map to `/subfolder/router.php`, since `filename` doesn't exist on the server (only `filename.html` exists).

But it serves/shows the `filename.html` file/page instead of mapping to `/subfolder/router.php`. Address bar still shows just `filename` without `.html`.

It works fine on my localhost, but not on the online server I uploaded the files to. I don't have access to the config files of the server.

I've read online, and looks like I'm on a virtual host, maybe?

---

I've tried:

- `Options -MultiViews` (gives error)
- `AcceptPathInfo off` (doesn't help)
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f` (nope)
- ... some other desperate ways of matching

Is there any way to force `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to not match extensions of files on the server when they are not in the URL?

Or at least somehow fix the problem?

I'm losing my mind right now, after hours of trying things and reading online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some thinking and trying things out, I solved it by changing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /subfolder/router.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule \.html$ /subfolder/router.php [L]
```

I'm not entirely happy, but it works for now, as the router.php file checks for file existence and uses a whitelist of files.